# Adoption of agricultural technologies empirical research

Tags: paneldata, agriculture, empirical-methods

At the moment I am working on my bachelor thesis about the adoption of agricultural technologies. More specifically, I want to study the effect of improved market access (infrastructure) and access to financial credit for farmers on agriculture productivity. I collected panel data for several Asian countries. However, the literature that can be found about this subject often focuses only on one country or a specific region in a country. The data used in such studies often come from local surveys.

So now I am wondering if a cross-country study makes sense. Or is cross-country data not specific enough to find significant relationships? At the moment, I feel like I'm stuck and don't know how to proceed. Is there someone who can help me?

Thanks for reading!